# GlideApp not generated with Glide 4.2.0

Tags: android-glide

```
1,I am using the sdk 26.0.2
2,adding repositories:
'

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

'
    3,create a class:
'

```
@GlideModule
    public class MyGlidApp extends AppGlideModule {
    }
```

'
4，adding dependencies`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "scrollview.custom.com.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

`
    5,make project
    6,no GlideApp class was found
     Can you help me with this? and I am trying this by create an empty project.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please do not post your personal contact info publicly. Although someone might be able to answer your question helpfully, StackOverflow is not your personal consulting service either.  The question seems reasonable though but perhaps you could post a clearer copy of the exact error message you got.  That is, what is the exact command you ran, and what is the complete and exact error message, verbatim.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: solved by rebuild,thanks for your comments.

Comment: I too had this issues, but when I observed the logs, there were other compilation errors too other than just Glide App not found. Once I solved the other issues and rebuilt the app it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use kapt in place of annotationProcessor in build.gradle dependency

kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'